# django-mailer getting [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: django, amazon-ses, django-mailer

In my project I'm sending my mails via Amazon Services. The thing is I have to send Daily Digests to all users in my system. That's why I thought it'd be a good idea if I use django-mailer to handle such a process.

I can send mails through django.core.send_mail successfully. When I try mailer's send_mail function, as expected mailer puts the mail into the queue but when I run the python manage.py send_mail, the system fails to send mails. I've checked the logs and it says [Errno 61] Connection refused.

I searched the web, and some posts says I should set up a smtp server, but it makes no sense because I can send mails with django's send_mail function. So I'm thinking that it can be something about amazon configurations but I'm not sure.

Any idea ?

Comment: What is your EMAIL_BACKEND set to and what are your settings for that backend?

Comment: EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend', I'm using this app: https://github.com/hmarr/django-ses and my

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to your settings:

> MAILER_EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'